# How to avoid first undefined subscription JavaScript RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to subscribe some object that I get from server. But  code for first time return me nothing. Code that is subscribe:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getEvents()
    .subscribe(
    (events) => {
      this.events = events;  
      console.log(events);   // when I try to get this is no problem it prints log to console (probably because event is var so it is not defined)  
      console.log(events[0].name); // it didn't see that property so I'm getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined          
    });        
  }
```

Service looks like this, I'm using `BehaviorSubject` for Observable:

```
 private eventChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.refetch();
  }
  private refetch(): void {
    this.http.get<EventE[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .subscribe(events => {
        this.events = events;
         this.eventChanged.next(events);
      });
  }

  getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    return this.eventChanged.asObservable();
  }
```

How to avoid this error and only subscribe event that is *Defined*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just add a filter to exclude undefined events on the initial subscription:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getEvents()
    .filter(events => events && events.length > 0)
    .subscribe(
    (events) => {
      this.events = events;  
      console.log(events);   // when I try to get this is no problem it prints log to console (probably because event is var so it is not defined)  
      console.log(events[0].name); // it didn't see that property so I'm getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined          
    });        
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a BehaviorSubject you can try using a Subject, the Subject won't have the empty array in the first place which triggers the initial subscription call.

If you need to use a BehaviorSubject, you can instead do a check for null and has length before working with it, so

```
.subscribe(events => {
  if(events && events instanceof Array && events.length > 0){
    this.events = events;
    this.eventChanged.next(events);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have to use BehaviorSubject thats the problem.. I tested that if statement but it didn't help still the same error